# is there anyway such that i can completely stop write operation if it is read only

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have read

> There is no guarantee that your method doesn't write into the
>   database. If you mark method as @Transactional(readonly=true),

If this is true, is there anyway such that i can completely stop write operation if it is read only OR its not at all possible?

Comment: why do you want to make `readonly=true` if you know its going to update the database?

Comment: My confusion is if i am calling some method that might have add,update code or let say even if i only by mistake added something that is updating the data, then?